# make all links on page have an image or affect added to them

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, styling

I have created a few screenshots in PS for a demo with a client. I am going to be hosting the demo and do not want to use InvisionApp or anything like that.

I am slicing up an image in PS and applying the proper paths to the links. Because they are going to be looking at this on a tablet I would like to make all the links have a border effect around the links or possibly an asterisk in the top left. This will allow them to know where to click.

Using a CSS border effect doesn't work because it offsets the slices and causes the images to shift. I need a way to layer on top the sliced image.

I am currently linking in the CSS or JS file and using the "a" in  tag to easily apply the style to the page. Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It would be cool if you can include a link to your code on jsfiddle.net

Comment: This is currently what I have: http://jsfiddle.net/mLqkn/

Answer (score 0):

Photoshop still slices everything out as a table, yeah? Which is likely why when you're adding the border it's causing everything to break.

You can actually give the elements what can really be described as an inner border. This won't make the boxes bigger.

```
a {
  box-sizing:border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
  border: 5px solid red;
}
```

or you can use inset box-shadow

```
a {
  -webkit-box-shadow:inset 0 0 0 5px rgba(0,0,0,1);
  -moz-box-shadow:inset 0 0 0 5px rgba(0,0,0,1);
  box-shadow:inset 0 0 0 5px rgba(0,0,0,1);
}
```

*Obviously change widths and colours to taste*

Myself, I prefer the box-shadow. It *should* interact okay with the image underneath it.

Comment: In solution 1, I get the same issue as when I put a border around the link. It offset the other images (slices).

The second solution doesn't seem to do anything. I change the inset value and colors and it wasn't able to appear on top.

Comment: Gotcha. Using the jsfiddle that you posted above... I put the border styling on the 'img' instead of the 'a' and got the desired effect.